# Do all my future users need a google account to access my web app hostet via GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-account

Total GAE beginner here.

Maybe total obvious answer. Maybe so obvious that I was not able to get a clear information via search because nobody spend even a single thought on it.

I just uploaded my first test app into GAE and in order to access it I need to login with my google account.

Why is that? If I want a login logic for my app, I will implement one by myself?

And if I do implement a custom auth mechanism: What is the user experience? Do a user need to first login into his google account and then into my app?

Do all my future users need a google account to access my web app hostet via GAE?

Clarification would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Switch to "Federated Authentication" [shown here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid#fa) to deactivate the google login screen.

Comment: I have made apps using GAE that do not require login from user and others apps that user can login using facebook or google+ .. So this is definitely something you have done in your project. It's not restriction from GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly shown in the google gae documentation. Even a google search about 'google appengine user authentication' shows in the 1st result: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I'm new to the whole topic of web app development and didn't recognized that OAuth is not just another way of forcing a login screen I don't want but actually gives me the freedom to do what I envisioned: Let the user choose how he likes to login ([like here](https://www.lucidchart.com/users/login)).

Comment: note that you can also choose to have no built-in authentication on some or all of your pages. In that case you can write your own login logic.

Comment: Thank you for your continued support. I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I think that it makes perfect sense to use given functionality as much as possible (e.g. user and session logic). I just try to make the right decisions regarding what tools to use in order to be as standard compliant as possible to ensure maintainability, security and longevity of my first web app. Right now I think a combination of app engine (hosting and persistence logic), gwt, html5 and css is a valid choice to achieve that... Long story short: You helped me to make a pro app engine decision: So thank you again :-)